Why does the H-NMR of propyl butanoate show up as 4 signals when there are 6 distinct hydrogens in the structure?

I am trying to learn NMR, but I cannot properly explain this. I understand that I can draw a resulting resonance structure, however, I do not see a plane of symmetry that would make the hydrogens on each side equivalent.
The illustration above is based on nmr 130 of a collection of NMR and IR spectra by Scott van Bramer, Widener University Chester/Pennsylvania, which itself is based on A Spectrum of Spectra and A Spectrum of Spectral Problems and Supplement by Richard Tomasi.

Your peaks are significantly broad and shimming is not ideal (you may see hint of doublets in two isolated triplets of A and B). Actually, methyl groups of ends are so much closely magnetically and chemically equivalent, two carbons away from carbonyl and oxygen groups to show any difference (signal D).  Signal C might able to show you a hint of two multiplets if the machine is well tuned. Higher resolution is also depend on your machine as well (higher magnetic field etc.).

TL:DR They aren't equivalent, but your spectrum is too lame too show it ;)

Based on drawing the structure in question

your presumption about the maximal number of signals is correct.  However, as already mentioned in the comments, the farther away the methylene $\ce{-{CH_2}-}$ group is from the terminal methyl group $\ce{-CH3}$, and the farther away the methylene group is from the ester, the smaller the differences in the chemical environment (shielding/deshielding electron density around the $\ce{^1H}$ nuclei).  In a routine 1D NMR spectrum, where $\ce{^1H}$ nuclei may couple with other $\ce{^1H}$ nuclei in proximity, the signals then can overlap (hence C, for example, with an integration of 4H) and become indistinguishable.
There are multiple ways to resolve (literally) this obstacle.  One relates on the spectrometer design, for instance by increase the magnetic field strength.  Instead of a bench top $\pu{60 MHz}$ spectrometer, use one of e.g. $\pu{300 MHz}$ (there are a couple of $\pu{900 MHz}$ instruments around, but typically used to characterize large biomolecules/proteins).  The design of the probe head is an other (e.g., if it is receiver coil for the $\ce{^{13}C}$ or the one for the $\ce{^1H}$ which is closer to the sample).
The structure elucidation by NMR is equally boosted by the many protocols of 2D or 3D correlation spectroscopy to resolve these overlaps.  It can be homonuclear to investigate the couplings between nuclei of one type (e.g., $\ce{^1H},\ce{^1H}$-COSY), or heteronuclear (e.g., $\ce{^1H},\ce{^{13}C}$-HSQC).  Wikipedia has a brief article* about this.  Advanced books about NMR spectroscopy (e.g., Silverstein, listed on the resources page) presents a couple in detail; Fields Organic Structures from Spectra and especially Organic Structures from 2D NMR Spectra offers training to correlate these spectra with structures.  By training and experience, you learn to combine (puzzle/crossword like) the information by MS/UV-Vis/IR/NMR etc to determine the structure of your molecule (ccc).

For an illustration, let's simulate a couple of 1D and 2D NMR spectra about your compound -- keep in mind that these predictions are idealizations, not a replacement of spectra experimentally collected, published in the literature or in databases (like SDBS, link to an isomer of your compound) -- on the freely accessible NMRium:

the idealized $\ce{^1H}$ NMR spectrum (presumed Larmor frequency of $\ce{^1H}$ of $\pu{300 MHz}$):



the idealized corresponding $\ce{^{13}C}$ NMR spectrum (already decoupled).  Note that its peak analysis, at level of the of the implementation of the computer program, predicts two overlapping peaks at $\pu{13.90 ppm}$.



the idealized ($\ce{^1H}$,$\ce{^1H}$)-COSY spectrum.  See the projections along the horizontal and vertical axis: they provide the same information as the 1D $\ce{^1H}$ NMR spectrum.  The new information by this technique is now to analyze the cross peaks where $\delta_1 \neq \delta_2$ (all but not the one "on the diagonal" of the plot).



as mentioned, this analysis is complemented by heteronuclear coupling NMR experiments, like ($\ce{^1H}$,$\ce{^{13}C}$)-HSQC for the coupling between $\ce{^1H}$,$\ce{^{13}C}$ nuclei across one bond.  Here, the 1D NMR of 1H is the horizontal, the one about the 13C is the vertical trace.  One of the information the HSQC now clearly displays is the signal of the carbonyl-C: because in the case of an ester this does not bind to hydrogen, it doesn't yield a cross peak.



similar as you can zoom in into 1D NMR spectra, this is used for 2D NMR spectra, too.  E.g., about our idealized HSQC spectrum:



and to complete this round, the ($\ce{^1H}$,$\ce{^{13}C})$-HMBC NMR spectrum where cross/correlation peaks are indicative for a coupling between $\ce{^1H}$ and $\ce{^{13}C}$ across one or multiple bonds.  See the peaks with the carbonyl-C with protons?


The key point to retain after these spectra is twofold: the spectroscopic identification of compounds usually requires data complementary to each other; based on the sample's history (e.g., what was the starting material, what was the intended reaction product) one has to select the NMR experiments most suitable.
* Brief in comparison to the (still growing) number of NMR protocols published/implemented in the programs to collect NMR data.
